# How to properly create OneToMany relationships in typeorm?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, many-to-many, one-to-many, typeorm

I'm having a problem in creating two entities with oneToMany and ManyToOne relationships between them.
These are my entities :

```
@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.photos)
    user: User;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

I tried to create a user and 3 photos that have relationship between them :

```
(async () => {
    const conn = await createConnection(typeOrmConfig);
    console.log('PG connected.');
    const photoRepo =await conn.getRepository(Photo)
    const userRepo = await conn.getRepository(User);
    let user1 = new User();
    user1.name = 'Matt';
    user1 = await userRepo.save(user1); 

    let photo1 = new Photo();
    photo1.name = "wallpaper"
    photo1.user = user1
    let photo2 = new Photo();
    photo2.name = "zanzibar"
    photo2.user = user1
    let photo3 = new Photo();
    photo3.name = "beach"
    photo3.user = user1

    await photoRepo.save(photo1)
    await photoRepo.save(photo2)
    await photoRepo.save(photo3)
    // Close connection
    await conn.close();    
})();
```

but whenever i try to print the users and photo , i cant see any relationship field between them(can't see photos in user/ user in each photo):

```
const conn = await createConnection(typeOrmConfig);
console.log('PG connected.');
const photoRepo =await conn.getRepository(Photo)
const userRepo = await conn.getRepository(User);
console.log(await photoRepo.find())
console.log(await userRepo.find())
await conn.close();
```

output :

```
[
  Photo { id: 1, name: 'wallpaper' },
  Photo { id: 2, name: 'Zanzibar' },
  Photo { id: 3, name: 'beach' }
]
[
  User { id: 1, name: 'Matt' }
]
```

I tried to access user.photos but its undefined
same when trying to access photo.user .
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: if you write some SQL like `select * from Photo`, what do you see?

Comment: @AluanHaddad 
`[
  { id: 1, name: 'wallpaper', userId: 21 },
  { id: 2, name: 'zanzibar', userId: 21 },
  { id: 3, name: 'naked nati', userId: 21 }
]`